# Getting a SEGFAULT from a referenced Vector

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault, sfml

**The Issue:**

So, I've been banging my head against the wall on this one. I have an application that compiles and runs fine on OSX and Linux, but when I compile it on Windows with MingW64, I get a SEGFAULT during run time. So here's what happens;

I have a Map Class which contains `std::vector<Tilesheet*> m_tilesheets`. I pass this Variable off into another class, MapLayer, by reference to the constructor:

```
    MapLayer::MapLayer(std::vector<unsigned int>& p_data,
                   std::vector<MindTrip::Graphics::TileSheet*>& p_tilesheets)
        : m_data(p_data),
          m_tilesheets(p_tilesheets)
{
    DrawTexture();
}
```

The vector gets stored as a reference in the MapLayerClass, `std::vector<MindTrip::Graphics::TileSheet*>& m_tilesheets;`

If I put a breakpoint on the first line of that constructor, m_tilesheets has a defined value for _M_First. If I put a break point at the last line of the constructor, m_tilesheets no longer has a defined value for _M_First. I am doing no multithreading, and the application has not yet left the scope these variables were defined.

In its next function called `DrawTexture()`, there is a foreach loop iterating through m_tilesheets which keeps giving me a SEGFAULT:

```
void MapLayer::DrawTexture() {
    for(unsigned int tile_val: m_data)
    {
        // SEGFAULT ON THIS LINE
        for(MindTrip::Graphics::TileSheet* tileSheet : m_tilesheets)
        {

        }
    }
}`
```

**Here is what I've tried:**

I have tried converting this to a regular for loop, but still get the same issue.

I have tried using references to grab objects from the vector by turning the foreach loop into this:
`for(auto& tileSheet : m_tilesheets)`. Same Problem

If I move m_tilesheets out of the MapLayer class & its constructor and pass it as a argument instead to DrawTexture as a reference:

`MapLayer::DrawTexture(std::vector<MindTrip::Graphics::TileSheet*>& p_tilesheets)`

M_data starts throwing a segfault instead in its foreach loop. Which is weird because m_data's foreach loop actually happens on the line before m_tilesheet's: `for(unsigned int tile_val: m_data)`

So, in response to that issue I tried moving m_data to an argument of DrawTexture and remove it as a member, just like I did for m_tilesheets, passed by reference:

`MapLayer::DrawTexture(std::vector<MindTrip::Graphics::TileSheet*>& p_tilesheets, std::vector<unsigned int>& p_data)`

At the time I tried this, I was using a for loop instead of a foreach. There should have been 1 entry in p_tilesheets and 10000 entries in p_data. This time the segfault threw at the line I was accessing p_tilsheet's data with `p_tilesheet[j];` `j` was not out of range and was set to 0.

After trying all this, I reset my code back to what it was, and instead decided maybe I will use std::copy() to copy the data in the vector, and instead of using references in the class, I just instantiated new variables for m_tilesheets and m_data. I switched the foreach back to a regular for loop and again, was getting segfaults accessing the element [j] of m_tilesheets.

I'm so baffled as to what is even going on with my memory. m_tilesheets and m_data are not null when they're being accessed, and their _M_First property gets unset somehow even before the end of the constructor.

Again, only happens on windows. OSX and Linux work fine. The application was running fine on windows before I implemented the map class. Not just looking for the fix as an answer, but the reason the bug is occuring.

**Edit:**

Here is the constructor to Map, where I am defining these values and passing them off to new instances of MapLayer.

```
Map::Map(const char* p_map_file)
{
         m_tile_sheets.push_back(new MindTrip::Graphics::TileSheet("PathToTilesheet", 0));

        std::vector<unsigned int> data(10000, 50);
        m_layers.push_back(new MapLayer(data, m_tile_sheets));
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: *Again, only happens on windows. OSX and Linux work fine* -- More than likely the same bug occurs in the program that runs under OSX and Linux, just that it is hidden / masked, or you're just plain lucky it hasn't had any visible indication something wrong is happening -- in other words, your program is not really "working fine".  Once you fix the Windows version, you will more than likely have to go back and correct the bug in the other versions.

Comment: Right, because the optimizer on g++ probably happens to make the issue not occur on OSX/Linux while MinGW might not make the same optimization, correct? Still learning C++ here.

Edit: Even weirder, just to update. I made another windows VM to test this with from my mac. The screen doesn't draw like it does on osx/linux, but the segfault just never happens. So, on a different system running the same version of the same OS, and the same distro of MingW, the issue is completely different. It makes me kind of wonder if it's just the way my environment is setup.

Comment: @DylanDodds -- It could be that, or it may be that you've introduced undefined behavior in your program, and the behavior for the versions that work is a "good" behavior.  Also `for(MindTrip::Graphics::TileSheet* tileSheet : m_tilesheets)` -- are you in any way changing the `size()` of `m_tilesheets` in that loop?  If so, UB.

Comment: I updated my last comment to include information about another test I just tried;

No i am not changing the size, only accessing the elements within the vector.

Comment: `std::vector<unsigned int> data(10000, 50);` This is a local variable. It goes out of scope at the end of the function it is declared in. You cannot hold a reference to a variable that no longer exists. You need to rethink who owns the data and what its lifetime is. The actual object needs to outlive the reference.

Comment: Right, I see the issue with that and I need to adjust it, but I don't think that's the cause as data is only used before we even exit that scope, and m_tilesheets is a member variable. attempting to test it now.

Comment: I moved p_data to a scope where it won't be destructed before MapLayer is destructed, i still get the same result.

Comment: @DylanDodds What exactly is `m_data` in the `MapLayer` class?  If it is a reference variable, then what RetiredNinja mentioned concerning lifetimes is valid.

Comment: It was originally a copy, I changed it to a reference to test. Regardless of whether m_data is a reference or a copied variable, the issue still exists. The same issue is also occuring with m_tilesheets as well.

Just made m_data a new variable and not a reference, passing by reference to the constructor still, storing as a copy in the class.

Comment: If only there was a [mcve] so we could see the whole picture,...

Comment: I'm working on simplifying the issue right now to reproduce.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is not occurring in the code you provided. This code is just triggering the bug. Also (as others also pointed out), your code is not working correctly on Linux & OSX, it's just not exhibiting the bug.

Since you are compiling on Linux as well, I'd suggest you to run your code through valgrind, and scan output for uninitialized variables, buffer overruns, etc...
To start it you might use the following:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --track-origins=yes --log-file=log.txt your_prog arg arg
```

after finished tun you will have (huge) amount of data to check contained within log.txt. Your problem will almost certainly be shown.

Other than that, I'd ask you why are you using raw pointers? If you don't have very good reason for this, I would suggest to use something else (smart pointers for TileSheets/MapLayers, and std::string instead of char*, for example). Naked pointers are "the quickest way" to create this kind of bugs.

Comment: I think you're right on the bug happening somewhere else, I just wrote a simplified version of this code and could not reproduce the bug with it. I honestly forgot about valgrind as its been a year since i've done any coding in C++. I'll give it a try, thanks.